# How to keep a photoshop plugin from being unloaded?

Tags: plugins, automation, photoshop, non-modal

I've written an automation plugin for Photoshop with Visual Studio 2005 and Photoshop CS2 SDK. When I click the menu, I want to show a non-modal dialog, which is created by ADM. Finally, when I got everything ready, and ran the plugin, the dialog appeared just fine. But when I looked inside the "module window" in VS, I couldn't find my plugin. How did this happen? Can I keep the plugin from being unloaded when the dialog is showing?

Comment: Seems I'll answer this question myself. Just make the plugin persistent, like the Listener from SDK sample (See Listener.r)